# Constant in Liouville's Theorem

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

So here's the well-know Liouville's theorem:

Let $\alpha \in \mathbb{R}$ be an algebraic number of degree $d.$ Then there exists a constant $c(\alpha)>0$ such that $$\mid \alpha - \frac{p}{q}\mid>\frac{c(\alpha)}{q^d},$$ for every $\frac{p}{q}\in\mathbb{Q}, q>0, \frac{p}{q}\neq \alpha.$

I encountered a statement that we could prove this theorem with the constant 
$$c(\alpha)=\Pi_{i=2}^{d}(1+|\alpha|+|\alpha^{(i)}|)^{-1},$$ where $\alpha, \alpha^{(1)}, ..., \alpha^{(d)}$ are the roots of the minimal polynomial of $\alpha.$

Does anybody have an idea? Or a hint?

Comment: You mean "$q^d$" , right ?

Comment: @Peter yes, thank you, I changed it!